# Run Python Module in Terminal Located in Subfolder of Current Directory

Tags: python, bash, terminal, python-module

I have the following folder structure:

- `main`

  - `tester`

    - `test_module.py`

The code in `test_module.py` is the following:

```
def test_func():
    print("Hello World!")

test_func()
```

When my current directory is `main`, the following command works just fine:

```
main $ python3 "/path/to/main/tester/test_module.py"
Hello World!
```

However, when I want to run the file as a module from main, I get the following:

```
main $ python3 -m "/path/to/main/tester/test_module.py"
/path/to/python/python3: 
Error while finding module specification for '/path/to/main/tester/test_module.py'
(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/path/to/main/tester/test_module.py')
```

The same happens when I omit the `.py` in the second command.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I need to run the file as a module and to run it from that location.

**Edit**

So I found a way to run the module as I intended to, by adding

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/tester"
```

to my `.zshrc` file. However that is more a hack than a solution as this clutters my `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Did you try to add an empty file with the name __init__.py in the /main/tester path? To indicate that this is a module?

Comment: This is for packages, not modules I think? But that also does not change the result.